# Firestore Transaction Fails on Read

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

In executing a `transaction` through `firestore`, my initial read operation fails the entire transaction with the following error: "nilError".

Just curious if you cannot complete a `transaction` if the document reference does not exist in the first place? Couldn't find a clear answer in docs for `transaction` in `iOS`.

I was hoping if the read was in fact nil where the document reference does not currently exist, to subsequently execute a `setData` versus an `updateData` write operation.

```
var db = Firestore.firestore()

db.runTransaction({ (transaction, errorPointer) -> Any? in

var document: DocumentSnapshot

do {

    try document = transaction.getDocument(self.db.document("path/nestedPath"))

} catch let fetchError as NSError {
    //Errors here.
    errorPointer?.pointee = fetchError
    return nil
}

if let documentData = document.data() {
    transaction.updateData([x: y], forDocument: db.document("path/nestedPath"))
}
else {
    transaction.setData([x : z], forDocument: db.document("path/nestedPath"))
}

return nil
})

{ (object, error) in
if let error = error {
    print("Transcation Completion Error: \(error)")
} else {
    print("Transaction Succeeded!")
}
}
```

Comment: It might help if you show some code.  That will make it easier to visualize exactly what's going on here.  Especially the line that gives you the error.

Comment: @DougStevenson please see the code above, following the example provided in the doc.